# Probability of having the same birthday without complement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

I understand the probability of getting at least n amount of people.Assume 365 normal days

> But I would someone to check if my reasoning for this particular question is right ?
> **I would like to know the probabiltiy that 12 people have the same birthday`P(W)`.**
> I am aware that we can find the complement `P(W)`, but is this also a correct thinking ?

```
We know the probability of one person having a birthday on any day is 1/365.
Another person A having the same birthday would then be (1/365)^2 because A needs to match that of the first person to be considered the same birthday
And so, like this 12 people would then give you (1/365)^12 ?
```

But, this is very much wrong and I am not sure where my logic fails ?

Comment: Ignoring the possibility that somebody is born on leap day, the probability that two people have the same birthday is $1/365$.  Say Amy is one of those two people.  The probability that somebody not born on leap day has the same birthday as Amy is $1/365$.  Do you see how to fix your argument?

Comment: $\left(\frac1{365}\right)^{12}$ is the probability all $12$ people have a birthday on a particular day, say 10 October.  But there are $365$ days in a year so you need to multiply that result by $365$ for the probability that all $12$ people share a birthday and you don't care which day that is

Comment: So, does that solve the problem then ? Is my thinking correct ?

Comment: As explained in the previous comment, you have computed the probability that all $12$ people were born on October 10 and none of them was born on any other day of the year. Is that what you were looking for? The usual "birthday problem" (the one that is solved using the complement of the desired event) is very different from this.

Answer (score 1):

> We know the probability of one person having a birthday on any day is 1/365.

This means that for any particular day, say Jan 1, the probability that a person having a birthday on that day is $1/365$. Similarly, the probability that $12$ people are born on a particular day like Jan 1 is $(1/365)^{12}$. However, you want the probability that $12$ people have the same birthday, where that birthday could be any of the $365$ days of the year. There are $365$ days, and for each day there is a probability of $(1/365)^{12}$ that the $12$ people will all have that day as their birthday. We add up the probability probabilities of these disjoint events to get the probability of at least one occurring. The result is $365\cdot (1/365)^{12}=(1/365)^{11}$.